# How to extract specific link in c#?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HtmlAgilitypack to extract some data from the following website:

```
 <div class="pull-right">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="social">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/wsat.a?ref=ts&amp;fref=ts" class="">
                <i class="icon fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="social">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/wsat_News" class="">
                <i class="icon fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/user" class="hide">
                <i class=" icon fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'Download', '');" href="https://wsat.com/pdf/issue15170/index.html" target="_blank" class="">

                PDF
                <i class="icon fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
```

I've managed to write this code to extract the first link in the html script which is https://www.facebook.com/wsat. However, all I want is to extract the link with the pdf which is 
https://wsat.com/pdf/issue15170/index.html but without any luck. How do I specify which link to extract ?

```
        var url = "https://wsat.com/";
        var HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);


        var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("pull-right")).ToList();

        var alink = links.First().Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;

        await Launcher.OpenAsync(alink);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an xpath expression as a selector:

```
var alink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//li/a[contains(@onclick, 'PDF')]")
    .GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Explanation of xpath (as requested):

Match `li` tag at any depth in the document with an immediate child `a` tag, which has an attribute `onclick` that contains the string `'PDF'`.

Answer (score 1):

In your query `Descendants("a")` selected you all links in the root div. And following `FirstOrDefault()` returns you just the first link. So what you can do is to map every link into its href, and then use string operation over collection to find appropriate.

```
        var alink = links.First().Descendants("a")
            .Select(node => node.ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault()?.Value)
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .ToList();
        foreach (var l in alink)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        var wsatCom = alink.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("https://wsat.com"));
        Console.WriteLine(wsatCom);
```

In addition. `?.` operator is needed after `FirstOrDefault()` not before, if you want to handle links without href. I believe in that case `ChildAttributes("href")` returns empty collection, FirstOrDefault returns null, and you've got null reference exceotion.

Answer (score 1):

Could Regex help you here? I think it will be a lot easier than using the HTML agility pack to traverse through the links and feels a lot less like a lucky shot.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"https:\/\/wsat\.com\/[\w\-\.]+[^#?\s][^""]+";
        string input = @"<div class=""pull-right"">
          <ul class=""list-inline"">
            <li class=""social"">
              <a target=""_blank"" href=""https://www.facebook.com/wsat.a?ref=ts&amp;fref=ts"" class="""">
                <i class=""icon fa fa-facebook"" aria-hidden=""true""></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class=""social"">
              <a target=""_blank"" href=""https://twitter.com/wsat_News"" class="""">
                <i class=""icon fa fa-twitter"" aria-hidden=""true""></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""/user"" class=""hide"">
                <i class="" icon fa fa-user"" aria-hidden=""true""></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onclick=""ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'Download', '');"" href=""https://wsat.com/pdf/issue15170/index.html"" target=""_blank"" class="""">

                PDF
                <i class=""icon fa fa-file-pdf-o"" aria-hidden=""true""></i>
              </a>
            </li>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of job I'd recommend using [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp)
It allows you to use css selectors to select whatever element you need.

```
var doc = new HtmlParser().ParseDocument(myHtml);
var pdfUrl = doc.QuerySelector("ul.list-inline a:nth-child(4)").GetAttribute("href");
```

or

```
var links = doc.QuerySelectorAll("ul.list-inline a").Where(a=> a.GetAttribute("href").StartsWith("https://wsat.com/pdf/")).ToList();
```

Bonus point is that you can always test your selector in any browser developper console without having to code/compile your C#